# find the index of one listbox and reference it in a for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having a problem in the way I set up a little calorie counter I was trying to do.
I loop through the food items in ListBox2 and find their fat and calorie content per 100g.
I then want to calculate the fat and content for the weight entered in TextBox1 which I have stored in ListBox1. Would anyone be able to help me with this?

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string foodName = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
// THIS IS WHERE I ENTER THE WEIGHT OF THE FOOD
        string foodWeight = TextBox1.Text;
        double Num;
        bool isDouble = double.TryParse(foodWeight, out Num);
        if (isDouble)
        {
            ListBox2.Items.Add(foodName);
// I THEN ADD THE WEIGHT TO LISTBOX1
            ListBox1.Items.Add(foodWeight);
        }
    }

    protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load("xml address");

        var texts = ListBox2.Items
            .Cast<ListItem>()
            .Select(item => item.Text)
            .ToArray();

        var texts2 = ListBox1.Items
            .Cast<ListItem>()
            .Select(item => item.Text)
            .ToArray();

        double totalFat = 0;
        double totalCalories = 0;
        foreach (string i in texts)
        {

            string fatValue = String.Format("Web_Service/Food[Name='{0}']/Fat", i);
            string calorieValue = String.Format("Web_Service/Food[Name='{0}']/Calories", i);
            XmlNode fatNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode(fatValue);
            XmlNode calorieNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode(calorieValue);

// I WANT TO FIND THE WEIGHT AND MULTIPLY IT BY THE FAT AND CALORIE CONTENT
// I was trying something like "weight = ListBox1[i]" or something along those lines
            totalFat += double.Parse(fatNode.InnerText) * weight / 100;
            totalCalories += double.Parse(calorieNode.InnerText) * weight / 100;

        }
    Label1.Text = totalFat.ToString();
    Label2.Text = totalCalories.ToString();
```

What I currently have now is in this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1al6.jpg. It just doesn't do the final "* weight / 100"

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try and use the ddl.SelectedItem.Text property to find the text associated with whichever item is selected. Or you also have ddl.SelectedItem.Value property which will get you the value of the selected item.